# How to load Image widgets from ByteData in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-image

The `multi_image_picker: 2.4.11` plugin returns a `List<Asset>`, each `Asset` having an `imageData` property that is a `ByteData`.

How can I show these in Flutter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `Image.memory` constructor.

```dart
List<Asset> assets = ...; // use multi_image_picker to get the assets

return ListView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  itemExtent: assets.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Image.memory(assets[index].imageData.buffer.asUint8List());
  },
);
```

Comment: how do you do it for version 4.6.0 of multi_image_picker?

Comment: AFAICT 4.6.0 still returns a `List<Asset>` from `pickImages`. It should just work the same.

Comment: if i key in assets[index].imageData.buffer.asUint8List()) its throwing an error sorry i am new to dart programming can you please walk me through?

Comment: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.images.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            var asset = widget.images[index].imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
            return Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Center(
                child: Image.memory(asset),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),

Comment: that's how I wrote it.

Comment: Here imageData is not working the version multi_image_picker: ^4.6.4

Comment: It says The getter 'imageData' isn't defined for the class 'Asset'. any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the function that will convert Asset -> Image**

```java
  Future<Image> assetThumbToImage(Asset asset) async {
    final ByteData byteData = await asset.getByteData();

    final Image image = Image.memory(byteData.buffer.asUint8List());

    return image;
  }
```